# Heroku won't seed when first user is self-referencing itself in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, self-reference

I'm trying to self-reference a user and so in my user.rb:

```
# return all users created under this user (admin/manager)
has_many :customers, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :creator_id
# return this customer's creator
belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
```

and in my schema.rb, in users table I have:

```
t.integer  "creator_id"
```

I have a seed file in Rails where the first declared user references itself (via creator_id). I tried the following which successfully seeds when I rails db:seed and I can run the app in localhost

```
u1 = User.new(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", email: "johndoe@example.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", role_id: r1.id)
u1.creator_id = 1
u1.save
```

However, when I seed in Heroku, it always throws me an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Creator must exist
```

which stops seeding the rest of the users. I'm wondering why my localhost is ok with it but Heroku won't let it. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your development environment's database might rely on ids that start at 1... but you can't assume that all databases will do that.

I suggest you actually pull out the creator's User model from your database and use the actual id that it has.

> "There are no user in the prod database yet. It is the very first user
>   I'm trying to seed. I can't create it so that the db will assign a
>   user id because it needs a creator_id which relies on its own user
>   id."

Ah... then you have a problem... because you've declared that `creator_id` must be present, your code will look for a `User` with the id you've given to `creator_id` and fail to find it... and thus you can't ever add the first `User`.

Depending on whether this constraint has been set up just in Rails (ie `validates :creator, presence: true`) or in the database `a proper database`NOT NULLCONSTRAINT`), will depend on the solution to use.

If it's just in Rails, then you can simply save the `User` without running the validation callbacks and *then* add the valid creator_id eg:

```
u1 = User.new(first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", email: "johndoe@example.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password", role_id: r1.id)
u1.save(false)
u1.update(creator_id: u1.id)
```

If there is a `NOT NULL` constraint in the db... then you will need to do all this via SQL only, but first turn off the CONSTRAINT...

Comment: There are no user in the prod database yet. It is the very first user I'm trying to seed. I can't create it so that the db will assign a user id because it needs a creator_id which relies on its own user id.

Comment: Some egs given based on above... do you have rails-only or a db constraint too?

Comment: It's all in Rails. I have no validation for creator so I think it's this line that's causing it to require it before saving *belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"*. I then made a custom validation method in the User model that accepts null values only if the table is empty: 'errors.add(:creator_id, "must be present") if User.any?'. I tried using 'self.any?' but it's not working so I used the model name itself. 

Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: I also added *optional: true* to that belongs_to line so it's `belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User", optional: true`.